# Installing fsmon to monitor Android phone File System

Tags: android

I would like to monitor the FS on my Galaxy S8 phone. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with adb to connect to my samsung. In my Ubuntu environment, i entered the following command:
make android NDK_ARCH=arm64 ANDROID_API=26

I then received the following response:

> for a in arm84; do \
>
> if [ -z ""]; then \
>
> ./android-shell.sh $a \
>
> make aagt21compile ANDROID_API=26 NDK_ARCH=$a ; \
>
> else \
>
> make aagt21compile ANDROID_API=26 NDK_ARCH=$a ; \
>
> fi ; \
>
> done
>
> Building android locally with NDK instead of dockcross......
>
> Invalid path in NDK environment, please change me.
>
> Makefile:166: recipe for target 'android' failed
>
> make: *** [android] Error 1

I am unable to take a screenshot of the error as my ubuntu computer doesn't have internet and I am quite restricted at my workplace in terms of transferring stuff from development to internet laptop.

I have installed Android NDK using `sudo apt-get install google-android-ndk-installer`

Please help!

Comment: You need to set NDK path for this to work. Better download latest NDK directly from Google. But why don't you use pre-built binaries: https://github.com/nowsecure/fsmon/releases? Or why not simply `inotifywait` or `busybox inotifyd`?

Comment: @IrfanLatif I tried installing fsmon-and-arm64 into my device but it was unsuccessful

Comment: I just tested the same binary on my phone and it works. But `fsmon` isn't necessarily required in your case. I have answered your question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/63062/53841